# I couldnt' prevent button arc

Tags: button, debounce, arc

[image]Guys i have a circiut in below. There is a problem: i couldn't fix how to prevent this arc on my button. At 2. & 4. pins of button have 100nF and a resistor 1M to series these 2. and 4. pins. When i try to put 10K ohm paralel to 100nF operating of circuit is being broken. Cause that 100nF capacitor makes latch circuit stay low at power up. Here are my circuit schematic and photo of arc of button.
I have put 4M7 to make any impact but no matter.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Zoom out and include the timebase and Y-axis scale so we know what we are looking at. Where is the probe connected?

Comment: Try putting a 100 ohm resistor between the 1 uF and the switch.

Comment: Prob connected to C11 capacitor that  .  I replaced 1M resistors with 100K. I got these results.. more damaged.

Comment: I think you mean "contact bounce" rather than "arc."

Comment: Yes actually contact bounce, and don't know how to fix. 100R was not a solution.

Comment: There are problem at both rising edge and falling edge of button signal as you see.

Comment: It is not contact bounce, nor arcing. I rather think it is **ground** bounce: a cap is not grounded well enough and gets lifted/pushed down when the NAND is switching

Comment: The emitter of Q10 is connected to GND and R22 as well. What's the function of Q10? Anyway, I'd recommend increasing C18 as you limit the current for U2 by R18. Maybe that's the cause of the whole problem. \$V_{DD}\$ of U2 may be fluctuating because R18 is too large and/or C18 is too small.

Comment: Q10 makes reset and pulls ground the 4011 while it is energized. @Huisman i Will try that u say

Comment: I did voltage divider  does  transistor turn on after 15V to prevent any interference. Normally 28VDC gonna come from there. @Huisman